# InnoDB database tables taking 51 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, locking, innodb

I have an PHP/MySQL eCommerce application that has a few innoDB tables (for the transactions). At random intervals there is a build-up of slow-queries (these take **exactly** 51 seconds) and these cause problems with accessing this single table.

The other MyISAM tables are fine - it is just this single innoDB table that crashes my application. There isn't any primary keys set on this innoDB table so cannot be anything to do with the primary key.

Furthermore when this error happens I get an 'Internal Server Error' - it is possible to force  the MySQL to display errors.

Any ideas suggest why these are taking 51 seconds & timing out?

Comment: Could you post the actual query or queries that are causing the slow down?  Also, posting the table structure(s) wouldn't hurt.

Comment: The internal server error is because your web server (most likely apache) is with default setting to wait your script to finish executing in 30 seconds, after that timeout and/or 'premature end of script headers' is received, and apache shows HTTP 500. Post the exact query. Also, not having a primary key is not a cool idea ;)

Comment: Do you use default mysql settings for innodb?

Comment: Did you check mysqld's logs? Did you enable slow queries log? If you did, please post this info. You should also have a look at `SHOW INNODB STATUS`. And, as Srikar said, you should accept some answers. People aren't much willing to help someone who asked 8 questions but never accepted any answer.

Comment: Hi - there is a table called protx_transactions with the following structure (this is the innoDB table) - the table has no primary key as i've read this causes problems with innoDB.

TransheadID int(10) unsigned Not Null
VendorTxCode varchar(40) Not Null
TxType varchar(15) Not Null
VPSTxId varchar(38) Null
RelatedVTX varchar(40) Null
SecurityKey varchar(10) Null
Amount decimal(5,2) Not Null
Currency varchar(3) Not Null
TxAuthNo bigint(20) Null

Comment: Here is the link to the code -

[link](http://pastebin.com/mcDyuWjC)

Comment: @Andrej - im a not sure it was a site I inherited and is very very old - how could i ascertain the default settings for innodb? thanks in advance

Comment: At first you should check in my.cnf innodb_buffer_pool_size. Default value is 8 or 16M. It's very small.

Comment: Hi guys - I have changed a few things for security reasons - the db you want to look at is called 'mysitedb' (do a quick Ctrl-F to find it)
Below is the output from the SHOW INNODB STATUS command provided by Mytskine above.
[link](http://pastebin.com/3ZFHPEm5)

Comment: Here is the output when I run a python script that display mysql settings etc..
Hope this helps a bit for you guys in giving me further advice.. I will try to keep posting related information.

[link](http://pastebin.com/0sLrgPKx)

Comment: I have setup innotop on the server (see the link below) - this is a python app that provides enhanced innodb stats (eg deadlocks etc..)
[link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/)

Hopefully this will provide me more info when this issue happens again?

Comment: Using advice from mysqltuner.pl above - do you think I should alter the following values in th cnf file? If so.. what would you guys recommend?

max_heap_table_size
tmp_table_size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change in my.cnf -> innodb_file_per_table
2. make backup
3. Change table type from Innodb to Myisam then Myisam to Innodb
4. Need Query and table structure
5. primary key And what about index ?
6. Try EXPLAIN SELECT .....
7. How big is your table ?